# how to implement a subclass's constructor?

Tags: c++

There is a base class :

```
class A {
public :
A(string a);
void some_method();
};
```

Implementation of A :

```
A::A(string a) {
cout<<"here it is : "<<a;
}
void A::some_method() { ... }
```

There is a class inheriting from A :

```
class B : A {
public :
B(string b);
void another_method();
};
```

Implementation of B :

```
B::B(string b):A(string a) // it causes error at compil time 
{
cout<<"here it is : "<<b;
}
void B::another_method() { ... }
```

What should I write in the implementation of the constructor of B ?

Comment: `B::B(string b):A(b)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call the base class constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923722/how-do-i-call-the-base-class-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line must read

```
B::B(string b):A(b)
```

You can remember this by thinking of the A constructor as a call, not a declaration.

Answer (score 1):

That would be simply:

```
B::B(string b):A(b) 
{
```

Like a normal object initialization (you initialize the base subobject `A` passing your parameter `b`).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a constructor like `B::B(string b):A(string a)`, how you expect the caller of the constructor pass the arguments? :-)

So if you want to use `b` to initialize `a`, you can do this: `B::B(string b):A(b)`. Otherwise, you have to do `B::B(string a, string b):A(a)`