# How do I use the constructor in inherited classes when the parent class doesn't have a default constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have a programming assignment in one of my college classes. The professor gave us specific code to work off of and told us not to alter his code. I am supposed to make a class called GameMgr that inherits from a class called Mgr. Here is a simplified version of what he gave us for Mgr.h:

```
class Engine;

class Mgr 
{
public:
    Engine *engine;

    Mgr(Engine *eng);
    virtual ~Mgr();
};
```

I am attempting to make a class called GameMgr:

```
class GameMgr: public Mgr
{
public:
    GameMgr(Engine* eng);
    void Run();
};
```

I get an error when trying to compile the code:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Mgr::Mgr()’
 GameMgr::GameMgr(Engine* eng)
                             ^
```

[I have made a pad on CodePad with an example](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/AXCZWMGGDB) (The example in the pad is meant just for this question and isn't my actual code but displays the minimum code needed for this question).

I have tried adding a default constructor to my GameMgr class but I still get errors. I'm assuming that it can be done, being that it is code from my professor, but the only way that I know to solve it is by changing the Mgr class to have Mgr().

How do I use the constructor in inherited classes when the parent class doesn't have a default constructor in C++?

I tried the solution for this question: [How do I call the base class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923722/how-do-i-call-the-base-class-constructor) in my CodePen example and it still isn't working. Therefore, I do not believe that is a solution to my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call the base class constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923722/how-do-i-call-the-base-class-constructor)

Comment: @Ari0nhh I have tried answer that in my CodePad example and it isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this example. I have used an `int` for simplification.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Mgr 
{
public:
    int a;
    Mgr(int _a):a(_a){}
    virtual ~Mgr(){}
};

class GameMgr: public Mgr
{
public:
    GameMgr(int _b):Mgr(_b) {}
    ~GameMgr(){}
    void Run();
};

int main() {
    GameMgr game_mgr(9);
    return 0;
}
```

[Sample-code](http://ideone.com/VJ5PyH)

Comment: I cannot change his code which has his constructor set the variable inside the code block.

Comment: I have not made any changes to `Mgr` class. To enable compilation for this example, I have added an `int` and indicated how it is initialized.

Comment: His code is this `Mgr(Engine* eng) {engine = eng}` not `Mgr(Engine* eng):engine(eng){}`

Comment: Both are more or less the same, one uses member initializer list and the other one does not. I would prefer to use member initializer list.

Comment: In the above code, you can replace `Mgr(int _a):a(_a){}` with `Mgr(int _a) { a = _a; }`. It will still compile.

Comment: Can you see what is wrong in the CodePen example: https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/AXCZWMGGDB

Comment: Destructor is not defined. I have defined it like this `virtual ~Mgr() {}`

Comment: So the only difference that I am seeing between your implementation and mine is mine is broken up as if it were in .h and .cpp files. It's not working for me.

Comment: I have made it to work. Check https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/AXCZWMGGDB

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138695/discussion-between-rishi-and-kingcobra1986).

Comment: @kingcobra1986 Also note that [you can mix member-initializer-list initialisations with in-body assignments, even doing a mix of both in the same constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0da3e8f531ceac34).  The difference is that 1) variables are initialised before entering the body (unless they're types that aren't automatically initialised on construction, such as `int`), so assigning in the body can assign to the variable twice, and 2) some types can't be assigned after initialisation, requiring them to be set in the mem-init-list (such as references or `const` types).

Comment: @JustinTime I'm aware of that, I just wasn't sure if it had anything to do with my issue

Comment: @kingcobra1986 Ah, okay, just making sure.