# The constructor take the parent class as argument

Tags: c++, decorator

I am using the Decorator design pattern. The decorator inherit from class Game and take game as argument.

```
    class Game {
       protected:
       int a;
       public:
       ~Game();
       Game(int a);
    };

    class Decorator : public Game{
       Game *m_game;
       public:
       Decorator(Game *game):m_game(game){}
    };
```

Then it returns error:  error: constructor for 'Decorator' must explicitly initialize the base class 'Game' which does not have a default constructor
   Decorator(Game *game):m_game(game){}
   ^

How can I fix it?

Comment: Call `Game(int a)`.

Comment: So wait, your `Decorator` is a game *and* has a game?

Comment: Your "design" looks fishy. You either inherit or contain.

Comment: Exactly as the error message says.   The constructor of `Decorator` must explicitly initialise its base i.e. call a constructor of `Game`.   If you don't explicitly invoke such a constructor in `Decorator`s initialiser list, the compiler defaults to looking for a constructor of `Game` that accepts no arguments.   Your example provides no such constructor to be called.

Comment: In the decorator pattern you aren't supposed to inherit from a concrete class type, but only from the base interface that exposes the relevant virtual methods. The decorator will implement them to do the additional processing you want to add and to forward the requests to the enclosed concrete instance that was passed in on construction.

Comment: This is emphatically **not** a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923722/how-do-i-call-the-base-class-constructor?noredirect=1&lq=1, if for no other reason than calling the base class constructor is the _wrong_ solution here, but also because it's a completely different question. Please take greater care with your dupehammers, folks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - there are actually two issues in this question.   The first is incorrect interpretation of what the Decorator pattern is.   The second is the specific question asked, which concerns diagnostic from the compiler due to the code, such as it is, relying on calling a base class constructor that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, but, regardless, the solution to the given problem is _not_ to arbitrarily construct the base class that shouldn't be there. By all means reference that in an answer explaining the diagnostic, but it doesn't fundamentally answer the question and cannot be a valid dupe.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - shrug.   I never tried to "dup-hammer" this question anyway.   But, that question which you say is "emphatically" not a dup does, more or less, address the question asked about the compiler diagnostic.    And that is something the OP should probably have an understanding of before trying to use design patterns in C++  (if one can't understand basics of the language, they can't expect to understand design techniques that rely on understanding basics of the language).

Comment: @Peter: We'll agree to disagree. In my eyes, that was not a dupe, period.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Either we answer the question that was asked, and if so, this is a dupe. Or we try to guess, what asker really needs. In this case it is "Unclear what you are asking" or "Too broad".

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: There is no need to guess anything. The question is clear and Matteo already answered it expertly and on point. Unfortunately, he did so in the comments section :( If you know what the Decorator pattern is then the question is not unclear; if you don't, this question is probably not for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of your base class requires an argument.
This will help (replace 0 with the respective value).

```
Decorator(Game *game) : Game(0), m_game(game) {}
```

In C++ if you define a constructor explicitly, compiler doesn't generate the implicit parameter-less one anymore.

Comment: This is likely to be the wrong solution. It's a backwards step.

Comment: Can be, but at least a starting point for him to investigate.

Comment: Not really, no.