# Waitable Queue - "no matching function for call to"

Tags: c++, exception, mutex, semaphore

I am writing a Waitable queue using Mutex, Semaphore and Exceptions and can't find why do I get some compilers errors, that is the first one:

> "../Include/SemaphoreException.h:17:90: no matching function for call
>   to ‘ImpException::ImpException()’ 
>   SemaphoreException::SemaphoreException(const char* _file, size_t
>   _line, std::string& _msg)"

Do I use badly the std::exception?

SemaphoreException code:

```
#ifndef __SEMAPHORE_EXCEPTION_H__
#define __SEMAPHORE_EXCEPTION_H__

#include "ImpException.h"

class SemaphoreException : public ImpException
{
public:
    SemaphoreException(const char* _file, size_t _line, std::string& _msg);
    virtual ~SemaphoreException() throw();
};

/************************************ should be implemented in a separated cpp file ************************************/

SemaphoreException::SemaphoreException(const char* _file, size_t _line, std::string& _msg)
{
    ImpException(_file, _line, _msg);
}

SemaphoreException::~SemaphoreException() throw() {}

#endif
```

and this is the ImpException code:

```
#ifndef __IMP_EXCEPTION_H__
#define __IMP_EXCEPTION_H__

#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class ImpException : public std::exception
{
public:
    ImpException(const char* _file, size_t _line, std::string& _msg);
    virtual ~ImpException() throw();

private:
    std::string m_msg;

    void Notify(const char* _file, size_t _line, std::string& _msg);
};


/************************************ should be implemented in a separated cpp file ************************************/

ImpException::ImpException(const char* _file, size_t _line, std::string& _msg) 
{
    Notify(_file, _line, _msg);
}

ImpException::~ImpException() throw() {}

void ImpException::Notify(const char* _file, size_t _line, std::string& _msg)
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << _line;

    m_msg = std::string(_file) + std::string(": ") + ss.str() + std::string(": ") + _msg;

    ss << m_msg;
}

#endif
```

Comment: I think you need to take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923722/how-do-i-call-the-base-class-constructor/30201944

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I call the base class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923722/how-do-i-call-the-base-class-constructor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
SemaphoreException::SemaphoreException(const char* _file, size_t _line, std::string& _msg)
// You are missing the call to the base class constructor here
{
    ImpException(_file, _line, _msg); // this does not do what you think it does.
}
```

It should look like this, because the base class constructor has to be invoked first:

```
SemaphoreException::SemaphoreException(const char* _file, size_t _line, std::string& _msg)
: ImpException(_file, _line, _msg)
{}
```

Your code is actually equivalent to this:

```
SemaphoreException::SemaphoreException(const char* _file, size_t _line, std::string& _msg)
: ImpException()  // compiler can't find this and complains!
{
    ImpException(_file, _line, _msg); // a momentary separate instance only.
}
```

Comment: Great.

So every time I use Ctor of a derived class and the base class should get parameters I need to put it in the initialization list in the derived Ctor? 

One more thing, does it matter if I make the Ctor of the base class Explicit?

Comment: The explicit keyword is irrelevant here. Base classes are always initialized before the members of a derived class, and all such initializations, when parameters are required, must occur in the initliallzation list, and _not_ in the constructor body.