# no matching function for call to c++ contructor

Tags: c++

I have a problem with c++ derived class constructor , I looked everywhere for similar problems but I dont seem to find any , I wish I will fin help in here.

basically I have a base classe with a constructor that has 4 parameters , and I derived a class from that base class but this time it has 6 parameters , 
both constructors are defined in a cpp file .

here are my files (in frensh):

```
 **Entraineur.h**

class Entraineur: public Personne {
public:
    Entraineur(std::string p_nom, std::string p_prenom, util::Date p_date, std::string p_num, std::string 
    m_numRAMQ, std::string m_sexe);
    virtual ~Entraineur();
private:
    std::string m_prenom;
    std::string m_nom;
    util::Date m_dateNaissance;
    std::string m_telephone;
    std::string m_numRAMQ;
    std::string m_sexe;

**Entraineur.cpp**

#include "Personne.h"
#include "Entraineur.h"
#include <string>
#include "Date.h"


Entraineur::Entraineur(std::string p_nom, std::string p_prenom, util::Date p_date, std::string p_num,
        std::string m_numRAMQ, std::string m_sexe) {

}


Entraineur::~Entraineur() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub

}


**Personne.h**

class Personne {
public:
    Personne(std::string p_nom, std::string p_prenom, util::Date p_date, std::string p_num);
    virtual ~Personne();
private:
    std::string m_prenom;
    std::string m_nom;
    util::Date m_dateNaissance;
    std::string m_telephone;
    std::string m_numRAMQ;
    std::string m_sexe;
};


**Personne.cpp**


Personne::Personne(std::string p_nom, std::string p_prenom, util::Date p_date, std::string p_num) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub



//setters 

        asgNom(p_nom);
        asgPrenom(p_prenom);
        asgDateNaissance(p_date);
        asgTelephone(p_num);
}

Personne::~Personne(){
    std::cout<< "detruit";
}
```

all the #includes are there.

please I beg for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call the base class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923722/how-do-i-call-the-base-class-constructor)

Comment: What's the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: The proposed duplicate assumes you are already aware that a non-default constructor of a base-class has to be called explicitly in constructors of derived classes. Providing a non-default constructor in base class, the compiler does not implicitly auto-generate a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) for you.

Comment: that was exactly the problem , that really helped a lot thanks yall