# error C2512 'vgui::EditablePanel' no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++

```
//The following include files are necessary to allow your MyPanel.cpp to compile.
#include "cbase.h"
#include "IMyPanel.h"
using namespace vgui;
#include <vgui/IVGui.h>
#include <vgui_controls/TextEntry.h>
#include <vgui_controls/Frame.h>
#include <vgui_controls/Button.h>
#include <vgui_controls/EditablePanel.h>
#include <vgui_controls/Checkbutton.h>

//CMyPanel class: Tutorial example class
class CMyPanel : public vgui::Frame
{
    DECLARE_CLASS_SIMPLE(CMyPanel, vgui::Frame);
    //CMyPanel : This Class / vgui::Frame : BaseClass

    CMyPanel(vgui::VPANEL parent);  // Constructor
    ~CMyPanel(){};              // Destructor
    vgui::TextEntry* m_pTime; // Panel class declaration, private section


protected:
    //VGUI overrides:
    virtual void OnTick();
    virtual void OnCommand(const char* pcCommand);
    //virtual void Activate();

private:
    //Other used VGUI control Elements:
    Button *m_pCloseButton;
    CheckButton *m_pCheckButton;

};

ConVar cl_showmypanel("cl_showmypanel", "0", FCVAR_CLIENTDLL, "Sets the state of myPanel <state>");
ConVarRef r_newflashlight("r_newflashlight");

// Constuctor: Initializes the Panel
CMyPanel::CMyPanel(vgui::VPANEL parent)
    : BaseClass(NULL, "MyPanel")
{
    SetParent(parent);

    SetKeyBoardInputEnabled(true);
    SetMouseInputEnabled(true);

    SetProportional(false);
    SetTitleBarVisible(true);
    SetMinimizeButtonVisible(false);
    SetMaximizeButtonVisible(false);
    SetCloseButtonVisible(false);
    SetSizeable(false);
    SetMoveable(true);
    SetDeleteSelfOnClose( true );
    SetVisible(true);

    m_pTime = new vgui::TextEntry(this, "MyTextEntry");
    m_pTime->SetPos(15, 310);
    m_pTime->SetSize(50, 20);

    m_pCloseButton = new Button(this, "Button", "Close", this, "turnoff");
    m_pCloseButton->SetPos(433, 472);
    m_pCloseButton->SetDepressedSound("common/bugreporter_succeeded.wav");
    m_pCloseButton->SetReleasedSound("ui/buttonclick.wav");

    m_pCheckButton->SetPos(200, 200);

    SetScheme(vgui::scheme()->LoadSchemeFromFile("resource/SourceScheme.res", "SourceScheme"));

    LoadControlSettings("resource/UI/mypanel.res");

    vgui::ivgui()->AddTickSignal(GetVPanel(), 100);



    DevMsg("MyPanel has been constructed\n");
}

//Class: CMyPanelInterface Class. Used for construction.
class CMyPanelInterface : public IMyPanel, EditablePanel
{
    
private:
    CMyPanel *MyPanel;
public:
    CMyPanelInterface()
    {
        MyPanel = NULL;
    }



    void Create(vgui::VPANEL parent)
    {
        MyPanel = new CMyPanel(parent);
    }
    void Destroy()
    {
        if (MyPanel)
        {
            MyPanel->SetParent((vgui::Panel *)NULL);
            delete MyPanel;
        }
    }
    void Activate(void)
    {
        // reset the data
        ConVarRef r_newflashlight("r_newflashlight");
        if (r_newflashlight.IsValid())
        {
            SetControlInt("r_newflashlight", r_newflashlight.GetInt() ? 1 : 0);
        }

        if (MyPanel)
        {
            MyPanel->Activate();
        }
    }
};
static CMyPanelInterface g_MyPanel;
IMyPanel* mypanel = (IMyPanel*)&g_MyPanel;

void CMyPanel::OnTick()
{
    BaseClass::OnTick();
    SetVisible(cl_showmypanel.GetBool()); //CL_SHOWMYPANEL / 1 BY DEFAULT
}

CON_COMMAND(ToggleMyPanel, "Toggles myPanel on or off")
{


    cl_showmypanel.SetValue(!cl_showmypanel.GetBool());
    mypanel->Activate();
};

void CMyPanel::OnCommand(const char* pcCommand)
{
    BaseClass::OnCommand(pcCommand);
    if (!Q_stricmp(pcCommand, "turnoff"))
        cl_showmypanel.SetValue(0);
}
```

Now I'm trying to get SetControlInt to be declared so in that case I made CMyPanelInterface inherit from EditablePanel, as seen here:

```
class CMyPanelInterface : public IMyPanel, EditablePanel
```

Now when I do this I keep getting c2512.

I searched it up and applied the fix I found on a StackOverflow post. But then I get these errors,

```
                                                                           Line-Col 
IntelliSense: no default constructor exists for class "vgui::EditablePanel" 88  2

                                        Line    Col
IntelliSense: expected an identifier    91      16

IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "vgui::EditablePanel::EditablePanel" matches the argument list     92  2

IntelliSense: expected a ';'        96  2   
IntelliSense: expected a ';'        122 1   

IntelliSense: object of abstract class type "CMyPanelInterface" is not allowed: 124 26
    pure virtual function "IMyPanel::Create" has no overrider
    pure virtual function "IMyPanel::Destroy" has no overrider
    pure virtual function "IMyPanel::Activate" has no overrider
```

There are 2 header file' that I have not posted yet because they make the post too long.
I posted them on pastebin
EditablePanel: [EditablePanel](https://pastebin.com/raw/YvQa4gkJ)
IMyPanel.h: [IMyPanel](https://pastebin.com/raw/9zr9Jt4U)

Can someone help me out?
Also please correct me if I said something wrong in this post I'm still new to c++

Comment: You might want to review [ask], in particular the part about introducing your question *before posting any code*.

Comment: You may want to review [mre]. If the compilation error cannot be reproduced with just the code directly in the question, then your example is not *reproducible*. But don't fix this by simply throwing more code into the question. Your goal is a *minimal* example. See what you can remove from the code while preserving the first compilation error. Try reducing classes to one or no members. Try eliminating base classes. Remove no-longer-needed headers. Try dummying up definitions from the required headers. Make no attempt to preserve functionality; stay focused on the compiler's error message.

Comment: Don't blindly trust IntelliSense. IntelliSense is a mostly-right guide, but your compiler is the authority. If you don't see how to fix something IntelliSense sees as an error, try compiling your code and see what the compiler has to say.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call the base class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923722/how-do-i-call-the-base-class-constructor)